# Why does declaring 'croppedImage' as 'any' resolve the 'string not assignable to type File' error?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to convert a base64 string to a file and i noticed something weird.

I have this line of code:

```
    croppedImage: any ="";
    this.croppedImage = this.toolImageService.getToolImage(); //it returns a string
    if (this.croppedImage) {
      const file: File | null = this.croppedImage;
```

and it works perfectly, however, if i remove the declaration `croppedImage: any ="";` then it gives me an error at `const file: File | null = this.croppedImage;` -> `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'File'`

Why if i declare `croppedImage` as an `any` then the code works, but it doesn't without it?

Comment: is the first line a class property declaration or is it inside a method? please show a more complete example if possible